# Adding PyDev eclipse pulgin manually

Tags: java, python, eclipse, plugins

I am on an assignment to work with Jython. I tried to install PyDev plugin to my eclipse ( Kepler service release 2  on Linux 64 bit machine )manually (dev machine doesnot have internet connection). But when I do manually by downloading   .zip file and adding it as following:

Help-> Install new software ->Add -> Archieve:

but I am getting an error.

No repository found at file:/home/lhananth/eclipse/dropins/PyDev%203.6.0.zip!.
No repository found at file:/home/lhananth/eclipse/dropins/PyDev%203.6.0.zip!.

I tried to manually add the unziped folders to dropin folder of eclipse but its not working as well- Python is not appearing as a selection in the Eclipse, Window, Preferences.

Can some body help me out ? (I tried all the replies for similar posts available in stack overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're just missing some slashes after file:
file:///home/lhananth/eclipse/dropins/PyDev%203.6.0.zip

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:
There was no issue with either eclipse or with PyDev. It was about the Java version I had. PyDev works with JDK 7, but I had JDK 6. Due to this even after I copied the PyDev to droppins, nothing was shown up in Preferences. Once I used JDK 7, its working.

Thanks,